# improve mysql query in large tables

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5, query-performance

I have a query to get data between current time and `INTERVAL 15` minutes

Table calls have 39790720 items;

```
SELECT src,unique,dstchannel,chan,calldate 
from calls 
WHERE calldate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND NOW() 
AND (dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT1/%' 
OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT2%' 
OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT3%' 
OR dstchannel REGEXP '^SIP/[[:digit:]]{10}-' 
OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT4%' 
OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT5%' 
OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT6%' 
OR dstchannel LIKE '%TEXT7%') 
AND lastdata NOT LIKE '%TEXT8%' 
LIMIT 39780720,39790720
```

```
Query 1 row in set (1 min 7.38 sec)

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| calldate    | datetime     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| colum1      | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| colum11     | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| src         | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| colum12     | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| chan        | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| dstchannel  | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| colum2      | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| colum3      | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| colum4      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| colum5      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| colum6      | varchar(45)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| colum7      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| colum8      | varchar(20)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| colum9      | varchar(32)  | NO   |     |                     |       |
| colum10     | varchar(255) | NO   |     |                     |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calls | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 39791545 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

When `%TEXT1%` is a variable only need contain like `'%Sip/phone%'` in value.

How to improve query?

Comment: Improve in what way?

Answer (score 2):

**To enhance the performance:**

- First of all, add an index on `calldate`. It will avoid you scanning the whole table.

**In the query:**

- Not sure what is `unique` in the query.
- `LIMIT 39780720,39790720` means, "Retrieve 39790720 rows starting from the row number 39790720 in the result". I think you want to revise it.

**About the table structure:**

- It is recommended to have primary key